# Multi-war maven build trouble

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

We have a monolithic code base. it looks something like this:

```
/
./project-a
./project-a/pom.xml
./project-a/facade/pom.xml  -> makes a war
./project-a/delegate/pom.xml 
./project-bean1
./project-bean1/pom.xml -> makes a jar
./project-parent
./project-parent/pom.xml -> makes a jar
./project-b
./project-b/pom.xml
./project-b/facade/pom.xml  -> makes a war
./project-b/delegate/pom.xml

bean1 -> depends on parent
a -> depends on bean and parent
b -> depends on bean and parent
```

we have an pom in . that allows us to build all projects as modules

So this is checked out by jenkins pipeline and built.  currently by going into each project directory and building them in the "right" order.

we have the ability to pass in the git-hash of each directory "project" into maven as the project's version.

We would LOVE to only build the war/jar if it's "project" has changed.

if the project has not changed then pull the war/jar of that version from nexus.

is this a pipe dream?  anyone have an example of this type of thing working?

Comment: If there is no change in the code why pull tha package from nexus?

Comment: First if you have a multi module build which sounds like that cause you mentioned having a pom file in `.` (this should contain module entries for the other)..If you have done it correctly you can simply do a `mvn clean package` or `mvn clean deploy` which means also having all modules the same version like `1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` etc.

Comment: Joao.  This build is happening in Jenkins, and is a "clean" workspace. 

step 1)  check out the code from git
step 2) build

So unlike when you run mvn in your work PC, and your able to rely on the local mvn repo.  Here there will not be one.  So if another build succeeds, might as well use it, unless the jar's it depends on have changed (shared beans etc) then you have to build it.. which mvn already does this..

Comment: khmarbaise - yes... so the agragate pom, or root pom is like this.. 

https://gist.github.com/jmvanryn/25455ca99eadeaf4bb27a4df68bc3127

app-ws and rest-api-ws both depend on the beans above...

if there is a change in the repo for rest, I would want to just pull down app-ws